# Artifactory Repository Browser with many directories

Tags: artifactory

I have created a new Maven Repository within my Artifactory Server and when I browse through my repository, I found that it has many folders inside it which I have not created. Just trying to understand what are they? and how to remove them to have a clean repository? Under libs-release, I can see many directories and some data are inside it. How can I delete them? Is this the default behavior?

[image]

Comment: If it is any comfort, mine looks the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libs-release is a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories), this means it aggregates artifacts from multiple repositories. Those can be [local repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories), where you deploy your company artifacts, or [remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) which are actually proxies for other repositories (usually public ones).

What you see inside libs-release, is coming from a remote repository pointing most probably to [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) or [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/).
Please note that probably those files are not cached yet in your Artifactory, but are shown as what is available in the remote repository.
If you select one of those item from the repository browser, you will see it is not cached

[image: Repository Browser]